# Who develops and maintains Ubuntu's "Network Manager"?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ppa, iwlwifi

Wi-Fi WPA3 (and Wi-Fi 6E which requires WPA3) use a new authentication and key management mechanism called [Simultaneous Authentication of Equals (SAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_Authentication_of_Equals).
This mechanism is further enhanced through the use of [SAE Hash-to-Element (H2E)](https://www.wi-fi.org/downloads-public/202012_Wi-Fi_Security_Roadmap_and_WPA3_Updates.pdf/37230)

SAE H2E is mandatory for WPA3 and Wi-Fi 6E.

SAE H2E is not supported in the versions of Network Manager (1.30.0), or WPA_Supplicant (2.9) provided with Ubuntu 21.04.

As far as I can determine, the only way Ubuntu can currently support WPA3 and Wi-Fi 6E is by building WPA_Supplicant from the [developer's source](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/), disabling Network Manager, and manually setting the network configuration in a wpa_supplicant.conf file.

I tried to determine the origin of Ubuntu's Network Manager, and found [this site](https://launchpad.net/%7Enetwork-manager/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (which was linked from [Ubuntu's help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)). The last code change seems to be in 2018. The "Choose your Ubuntu Version" drop down has Ubuntu 12.04 as the latest.

Has Network Manager development moved? Where could I go to get involved, or at least file a bug report? Or is there another approach to obtain SAE H2E support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `apt show network-manager` points you to its homepage:

> Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager

Then, you can proceed to [the Git](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager).

Answer (score 1):

If you type `man networkmanager`, you will see some links at the bottom of the page:

> NOTES
>
> 1. NetworkManager bug tracker
>
>    https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=NetworkManager
> 2. NetworkManager home page
>
>    https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager

The link you found is a PPA, i.e. somebody's Personal Package Archive, which is by definition not the official place for packages. Those PPAs may be abandoned after a while which seems to be the case here.

Comment: thank you. the gnome.org link redirects to https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/new.   The latest change is hours ago, so I think I'm in the right place!

Comment: Also don't forget the mailing lists and the IRC channel that they have.