# Tutorial on updating Ubuntu with developer versions newer than the official releases?

Tags: apt, updates, network-manager, 21.04, wpa-supplicant

In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347811/who-develops-and-maintains-ubuntus-network-manager/1347812?noredirect=1#comment2303650_1347812) I learned where Network Manager is developed.
I posted an [issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/753) there, and was told to not post issues that are not tested on the "latest version."  Apparently Ubuntu 21.04 with all updates is not the latest version.

Can anyone point me to a basic tutorial on how to update specific parts of Ubuntu to developer versions newer than the official distribution releases and updates?

Comment: Of course, you can compile the [latest version](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/tags) from source, but is not recommended to change the version numbers of such core components of Ubuntu, as you may end up with a computer that cannot connect to the internet. An easier way would be to test the latest version of the package with a live USB running a beginner friendly rolling release distribution (e.g. Manjaro unstable branch, which already has v1.32 of this program). Alternatively, you could use Ubuntu 21.10 daily builds, but it still has v1.30 of this program.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 has v1.30.0 of this program, as you can see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=network-manager)

Comment: I know I need Network Manager beyond 1.30, I'm running 21.04 and 1.30 is not considered "the latest".  Maybe 1.32 is "the latest".  I also need "the latest" wpa_supplicant. I know 2.9 is not, and the "master" branch here `https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/` is, but it is not clear what version it would build to since I have not tried to build it.   I'll look into Manjaro Unstable and see if it has a newer wpa_supplicant beyond 2.9.